# Nuke thumbdrive and set GPT+Partition

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, formatting

After using my 16GB USB2.0 thumbdrive as an ESXi boot stick I am now unable to format it. Windows Explorer would just say:

> The drive could not be formatted (or something likewise)

Diskpart is able to create a primary RAW partition, but is also unable to format it.

GParted on Linux Mint 17.1 is also unable to format the stick:

> The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.

Also it claims the stick has a size of 59,66GiB.

Is there a way to completely nuke the stick and then manually set it up again?

EDIT: The GParted Live-CD was also unable to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem myself using *gdisk*. In fact no other program was able to tell me what's really the problem. It's this:

> Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
>   in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
>   typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
>   to GPT format!

AND

> Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
>   3657528735 blocks!
>   You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

What I did:

Delete all partitions on stick:

```
Command (? for help): d
Partition number (1-4): 1

Command (? for help): d
Partition number (2-4): 2

Command (? for help): d
Partition number (3-4): 3

Command (? for help): d
Using 4
```

Create new MBR

```
Command (? for help): o
This option deletes all partitions and creates a new protective MBR.
Proceed? (Y/N): y
```

Verify disk

```
Command (? for help): v
No problems found. 31276989 free sectors (14.9 GiB) available in 1
segments, the largest of which is 31276989 (14.9 GiB) in size.
```

Write to disk

```
Command (? for help): w
Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sdb.
The operation has completed successfully.
```

After that I was able to format the stick as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Glad you answered your own question. OK, usually, the way to nuke a disk is to zero-out the partition table with `dd if=/dev/zero of=<RAW-DEVICE> bs=512 count=1`.

That would be the end of the story, but apparently doing so might be prevented by the OS. Via Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Legacy_MBR_.28LBA_0.29

> Operating systems and tools which cannot read GPT disks will
>   generally recognize the disk as containing one partition of unknown
>   type and no empty space, and will typically refuse to modify the disk
>   unless the user explicitly requests and confirms the deletion of this
>   partition.

This somewhat explains your error messages and what happened to you: the GPT is linked-to in the MBR, and your OS saw a valid MBR but an invalid GPT.